# home partition space is considred as part of root partition space

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 recently, and recently I have noticed that my system is considering home partition space as part of root partition space.
Home and Root are totally on different sectors of my hard-disk.
Now whenever I have some files on my home folder I face a warning message that my space on root is going to be full soon and I should delete some files.
Any ideas how  to solve this ?
here is a screenshot of what I am seeing

[Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjN5T.jpg)

Comment: Post these above as text & preserve formatting. `lsblk -f` and `df -h` the graphical tools do not always show the details.

Comment: here you can find the output of these two commands 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VvZnMJxfDP/

Comment: You do not have anything mounted at /home or /home/your_user